# Как прочитать JSON в Delphi?

Tags: json, delphi

Использую библиотеку `System.JSON`. Пробую вот так:

```
buf:=TFile.ReadAllText(Dir + SR.Name);
JSONValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(buf);
try
  if JSONValue is TJSONArray then
  begin
    for jv in TJSONArray(JSONValue) do
    begin
      showmessage(jv.GetValue<string>('Name'));
    end;
  end;
finally
  JSONValue.Free;
end;
```

`JSONValue` в итоге пустой.

Comment: Что находится в файле?

Comment: данные в формате json

Comment: Добавьте их в вопрос.